# Get output of console process as it is running

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, console-application, windows-console

I have viewed many stack overflow questions about getting the output of an console process, but my application is a very long one, and just waiting for it to exit and reading the output wont work. I would apprectiate and input, thanks.

Comment: Then read the output stream as it's running.  You can pass in the streams to the process create, just read from them.

Comment: If you're in control of the source, you'll probably want to ensure that stdout uses line buffering or no buffering. If you rely on the default behavior, it will switch to full buffering when writing to a pipe. Full buffering is good if a program writes a large amount of data; fine if it writes a small amount and quickly exits; but a hindrance if you need to interact with the process.